# Multiple User Controls referencing the same object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, user-controls

I have created a UserControl in C# that I have put a DataGridView on.
When I have only one instance of this UserControl in a WinForms project, it works like intended.
When I have two instances of this UserControl in a WinForms project, the second instance of my UserControl behaves the way it should but the first one does not.

It seems like both UserControl instances reference the same instance of the DataGridView some how.

I would much appreciate any advice in this matter.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you reduce your code to the bare minimum to reproduce the problem and post it for us to see. It's a little hard to come up with a diagnosis if we can't see the patient.

Comment: Do you have any code to share? It's possible you have static variables where you should not. Are you making a copy of the object or creating new instances?

@ChrisF: Come on... channel your inner Dr. House :)

Comment: Oh, this is so embarrasing!
I had made a property in the UserControl class to expose the DataGridView object to the client code. And sure enough, I had made the variable referencing the DataGridView a static one. 
I guess 12 hours of coding late at night make you do these misstakes. :)

Thank you for "reviving me". :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you exposed a property on the UserControl that sets/gets the GridView's Datasource? (You can't do this in the UserControl or else you would see the behaviour you are seeing)